# Error:"Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression" in the component which implements user registration.Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I need to implement **register** and **authorize** in my application.

At the moment, I've implemented this:

- In case of successful validation of the form by the user, the form is sent to the local server (located in my computer) and it returns a response, this response contains a token which I store in localStorage

Small part **SignupForm.js**(before changes, works fine):

```
const SignupForm = () => {

    const {handleSubmit, values, handleChange, errors, handleBlur, isSubmitting, setSubmitting} = useFormik({  
      initialValues: {
         /.......
      },
        validateOnBlur: false, 
        validateOnchange: false,
        validationSchema: yup.object().shape({    
          /.......
      }),   
      onSubmit: async (formValues) => {
          console.log('submit', formValues);
          setSubmitting(true);
          try {
              const res = await api('api/auth/register', {
                  method:'POST',
                  body: JSON.stringify(formValues)
              });
              const token = res.token.token;
              localStorage.setItem('myToken', token);
              console.log('Result!',token);
          } catch(e) {
              console.error(e);   
          } finally {
              setSubmitting(false);
          }   
      },  
    });

   return (
   <form className="fform" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>   
       /........
       <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>Submit Form</button>       
   </form>
   );
};
```

But I still need to do this:

- When the user validation in the registration form was successful and
        user presses the button `submit` should be redirected to the
     `home` page
- The same redirect must occur during authorization
- When I press button `logout` should be redirect to
  `login` page or `registration` page

And I decided to implement it this way(I comment line which I add, and line where error):

```
const SignupForm = () => {

    const [myToken, setMyToken] = useState(         // add this line
       localStorage.getItem("myToken")              // add this line
    );


    myToken ? <Redirect to="/home" /> : <Redirect to="/" />  // add this line.I have error here

    const {handleSubmit, values, handleChange, errors, handleBlur, isSubmitting, setSubmitting} = useFormik({  
      initialValues: {
         /.......
      },
        validateOnBlur: false, 
        validateOnchange: false,
        validationSchema: yup.object().shape({    
          /.......
      }),   
      onSubmit: async (formValues) => {
          console.log('submit', formValues);
          setSubmitting(true);
          try {
              const res = await api('api/auth/register', {
                  method:'POST',
                  body: JSON.stringify(formValues)
              });
              const token = res.token.token;
              localStorage.setItem('myToken', token);
              console.log('Result!',token);
          } catch(e) {
              console.error(e);   
          } finally {
              setSubmitting(false);
          }   
      },  
    });

   return (
   <form className="fform" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>   
       /........
       <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>Submit Form</button>       
   </form>
   );
};
```

And I have **error**:

> `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression`

How should you write the code to prevent such an error?

Also I will write the **sandbox** project before the changes:

https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-neumann-hwj1t

In sandbox in folder `public/data` I created file `data.json` because I use local server in my computer and cannot transfer data from the local server to the sandbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to programmatically redirect with React Router, you have to use a special function, not a component:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const SignupForm = () => {
    const history = useHistory();

    const {handleSubmit, values, handleChange, errors, handleBlur, isSubmitting, setSubmitting} = useFormik({  
      initialValues: {
         /.......
      },
        validateOnBlur: false, 
        validateOnchange: false,
        validationSchema: yup.object().shape({    
          /.......
      }),   
      onSubmit: async (formValues) => {
          console.log('submit', formValues);
          setSubmitting(true);
          try {
              const res = await api('api/auth/register', {
                  method:'POST',
                  body: JSON.stringify(formValues)
              });
              const token = res.token.token;
              localStorage.setItem('myToken', token);
              console.log('Result!',token);

              history.push("/home");  //redirect
          } catch(e) {
              console.error(e);   
          } finally {
              setSubmitting(false);
          }   
      },  
    });

   return (
   <form className="fform" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>   
       /........
       <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>Submit Form</button>       
   </form>
   );
};
```

You can do such a redirect in all the other places, where you need to change the url.

Here's how you could implement your "/home" to redirect the unauthorized users.

```
const Home = () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("myToken")

    return (
        <>
            {!token && <Redirect to="/" />}
            <p>Home page</p>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: thank you, but i need that in case there is no token in localStorage, I could not go to the page / home, and now it is possible when i just write in the path /home. That is, I need to prevent unregistered users from accessing the home page. I tried to write something like this:
```if(token){    history.push("/home");  else{   history.push("/");  }```. But it doesn't work.Can you tell me how to do it? If you know how to do this add it in the answer.

Comment: There is no way to perfectly prevent users from entering your home page, because a malicious user could always remove any checks you implement. Though I will add an example "/home" page, that would at least redirect the "normal" users, that won't tamper with the source :)

Comment: Ok, you can have a try this

Comment: I wrote so in the Home.js file and now does not want go to the home page at all. And in console such error:
```Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in SignupForm (created by Context.Consumer)```

Comment: Could you provide your `Home.js`?

Comment: @bimsalrobit you could do the same in the part of your code that decides which component to show and it should work fine then

Comment: ```you could do the same in the part of your code that decides which component to show and it should work fine then```. I dont uderstand you

Comment: If you put the code I described as `Home` inside your `Switch` for the routes, it should work correctly

Comment: In file App.js where I have switch I write like this:
http://i.piccy.info/i9/1940fcf545bbe12596edcbab668842e9/1586536410/131009/1372209/a.png
did I not understand you? it doesn't work. maybe you change needed file in sandbox?
just so it will be faster.
https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-neumann-hwj1t

Comment: or add it in the answer

Comment: I'm very sorry for the unnecessary trouble, I used `()` instead of `{}`, which meant that the "/home" route was always redirecting... Fixed now, the code for the `Home`, should be working :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is this:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const SignupForm = () => {
    const [myToken, setMyToken] = useState(localStorage.getItem("myToken"));
    const redirectUrl = myToken ? '/home' : '/'; // Updated this line

    const { handleSubmit, values, handleChange, errors, handleBlur, isSubmitting, setSubmitting } = useFormik({  
      initialValues: {
        /.......
      },
      validateOnBlur: false, 
      validateOnChange: false,
      validationSchema: yup.object().shape({    
          /.......
      }),   
      onSubmit: async (formValues) => {
          console.log('submit', formValues);
          setSubmitting(true);
          try {
              const res = await api('api/auth/register', {
                  method:'POST',
                  body: JSON.stringify(formValues)
              });
              const token = res.token.token;
              localStorage.setItem('myToken', token);
              history.push(redirectUrl);  // Redirect to appropriate route path
          } catch(e) {
              console.error(e);   
          } finally {
              setSubmitting(false);
          }   
      },  
    });

   return (
     <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>   
       /........
       <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>Submit Form</button>       
     </form>
   );
};
```

Above I set a variable `redirectUrl` which will hold the path to redirect to based on the availability of a token. Then later used `history.push` from the `useHistory` hook to redirect to the url from the previously assigned variable.

Comment: thank you, but i need that in case there is no token in localStorage, I could not go to the page / home, and now it is possible when i just write in the path /home. That is, I need to prevent unregistered users from accessing the home page. I tried to write something like this: ```if(token){ history.push("/home"); else{ history.push("/"); }```. But it doesn't work.Can you tell me how to do it? If you know how to do this add it in the answer.

Comment: I already did that on line 3 where I set the `redirectUrl` based on the token.. Please have a look.